# map return -1 when I use $stateParams

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I trying to pass a variable to a page, so my url is: `http://localhost/project/#/app/intro/1`

and route to my controller, everything is ok but when I trying to `map` an array in my controller I have problem !

my code is :

```
console.log($stateParams.userId); // return 1
var ePos = $rootScope.data.users.map(function (x) {
    return x.id;
}).indexOf($stateParams.userId);
console.log(ePos); // return -1
```

but when I trying to use static data everything is ok

```
  console.log($stateParams.userId); // return 1
    var ePos = $rootScope.data.users.map(function (x) {
        return x.id;
    }).indexOf(1);
    console.log(ePos); // return 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I created [working plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/9LbQaiLHg6Be0mnPQoG3?p=preview)

The problem here is in `type` - id is a `string`, while we need `int`. Check this example

```
// here we force ui-router to act with id as INT
.state('int', {
   url: "/int/{id:int}",
   templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
   controller: 'MyCtrl',
})
// here we leave it as is - so it is a string "1"
.state('str', {
   url: "/str/:id",
   templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
   controller: 'MyCtrl',
})
```

And these links

```
// these will return id as a 'number'
<a href="#/int/1">int/1</a>
<a ui-sref="int({id:2})">int({id:2})</a>

// these will have string as id
<a href="#/str/3">str/3</a>
<a ui-sref="str({id:4})">str({id:4})</a>
```

Check the [example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/9LbQaiLHg6Be0mnPQoG3?p=preview)

EXTEND ([and extended plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/O3kG9K2DSXILnCbMeHu3?p=preview))

Based on comments, we can have states like this:

```
.state('app', {
  url: "/app",
  templateUrl: 'tpl.app.html',
})
.state('app.userIntro', {
  url: "/intro/{userId:int}",
  views: {
    'menuContent': {
      controller: 'UserIntroCtrl',
      templateUrl: "templates/intro.html"
    }
  }
})
```

And the call could be like this:

```
<a href="#/app/intro/1">app/intro/1</a>
<a href="#/app/intro/2">app/intro/2</a>
<a ui-sref="app.userIntro({userId:3})">int({userId:3})</a>
<a ui-sref="app.userIntro({userId:4})">int({userId:4})</a>
```

Check the [extended version](http://plnkr.co/edit/O3kG9K2DSXILnCbMeHu3?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks, should I change my `href` to `ui-sref="app/intro({userId:1})"` ?

Comment: NO. no. The issue hre should be fixed with state defintion `url: "/intro/{id:int}",`. Then ui-sref needs state name and object with params so it should be `ui-sref="app.intro({id:1})` (if `'app.intro'`) is state name. Not `app/intro`, where app/intro is url. Is it more clear? does it help? Check my example... there should be everything you need. ;)

Comment: Yes, but when I change my url, application cannot route and page will redirect to `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/welcome');`, my first page. my state is : `.state('app.userIntro', {
                url: "/intro/{userId:int}",
                views: {
                    'menuContent': {
                        controller: 'UserIntroCtrl',
                        templateUrl: "templates/intro.html"
                    }
                }
            })`

Comment: I am ready to assist, but now I do not understand. Could you take my plunker adjust it and show me the issue? Because... if you define state properly, then ui-sref will always navigate to suche state. And pass all params

Comment: I updated my plunker here http://plnkr.co/edit/O3kG9K2DSXILnCbMeHu3?p=preview... it should give you idea

Comment: Thanks, I can understand, and changed my code, everything seems to be ok but I don't know why after changing page to `intro`, the page will redirect to ` $urlRouterProvider.otherwise` immediately. I use `console.log('here');` in `UserIntroCtrl` so I can understand my script will run

Comment: Really not sure.. without example. But ... the otherwise could be `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app');` This will navigate to app state.. at the begining and if wrong url is passed. Hope it helps. Check my examples and play with.. you should get the answers there